# dispose/unsubscribe inside subscribe function block in rxjs

Tags: javascript, rxjs5

I've a **subject** called **authenticated** in **_auth** service.

I want to **dispose/unsubscribe** it **if some condition fails** so that this subscribe doesn't call when next value arrives in authenticated subject.

```
                this.sub = this._auth.authenticated
                .subscribe((loggedIn) => {
                    if (!loggedIn) {
                        this.sub.dispose(); // doesn't work because this.sub is null
                        this._location.replaceState('/');
                        this._auth.doLogout(); // emits value again in authenticated subject
                    }
                });
```

What is the rxjs-5 way of doing it?

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

You hold a reference to the observable Eg: obs$ and call obs$.unsubscribe();

Answer (score 0):

You can just do this `this.sub.unsubscribe();` from out of subscription.

Comment: But what if the question poster wants to unsubscribe the subscription eventually by a certain loggedIn event inside the subscription?